# Simulate a synchronous request on top of background async job with Flask

Tags: python-2.7, http, flask, rabbitmq, polling

I'll first explain the architecture of my system and then move to the question:

I have a REST API which is used as my API gateway. This server is build using Flask. I also have RabbitMQ cluster, and a client I wrote that listens to a specific queue and executes the tasks its getting.

Until now, all of my requests were asynchronous, so once a request has reached to the API gateway, a `callback_uri` field with URL to POST the results to provided as part of the request, and the API gateway was just responsible for sending the task to RabbitMQ and the worker processed the task, and at the end POSTed the results back to the callback URL.

**My question is:**

I want a new endpoint to be synchronous in the sense of, that the processing will be done still by the same worker as before, but I want to get the results back to the API gateway to return to the user and release the connection.

**My current solution:**

I'm sending a unique `callback_uri` as part of the request to the worker as before, but now the specific endpoint is implemented by my API gateway and allow both POST and GET methods, so the worker can POST the results once it finished, and my API gateway keeps polling the callback URL until a result is available and then return the result to the client.

Is there any other preferred option other than having a busy-waiting HTTP worker polling its own endpoint to get the results? but still be synchronous so the connection released only when the results become available?

**Code for illustration only:**

```
@app.route('/long_task', methods=['POST'])
@sync_request
def long_task():
    try:
        if request.get_json() is None:
            return ERROR_MSG_NO_JSON, 400
        create_and_send_request_to_rabbitmq()
        return '', 200
    except Exception as ex:
        return ERROR_MSG_NO_DATA, 400


def sync_request(func):

    def call(*args, **kwargs):
        create_callback_uri()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        status_code = result[1]
        if status_code == 200:
            result = get_callback_result()
        return result

    return call

def get_callback_result():
    callback_uri = request.get_json()['callback_uri']
    has_answer = False
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    empty_response = {}
    content = json.dumps(empty_response)

    try:
        with Timeout(seconds=SYNC_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS):
            while not has_answer:
                response = requests.get(callback_uri, headers=headers)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    has_answer = True
                    content = response.content
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.2)
    except TimeoutException:
        log.debug('Timed out on sync request for request %s ' % request)

    return content, 200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you want your backend to wait for the response from some worker (via RabbitMQ). You can achieve that by implementing [rpc over rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html). The key idea is to use the correlation id.

But definitely the most efficient way would be to run the client over websockets (or raw tcp socket if it is not a browser) and notify him directly when the job is done. That way you don't lock resources (client connection, rabbitmq queues) and you avoid performance hit (rpc).

Comment: Regarding the tcp sockets solution, how does the backend would know when to notify and what to notify about? Does the RPC solution should still be used along with the tcp sockets solution?

Comment: @AvihooMamka RPC solution can be implemented over classical HTTP. You would just modify your `long_task` to wait for the response from RabbitMQ. As for TCP: the backend does't know when to notify. But the worker knows. So he notifies the backend (it can do it via classical HTTP request, it also has to know which backend, so you have to send additional info via RabbitMQ) and then the backend notifies the client (the backend keeps track of all connected clients). This might be quite tricky to implement though, you have to remember about edge cases (e.g. random disconnections).

Comment: I'm not sure I understood how this can work with having the client send an HTTP POST request and must wait until a response is back. Like, how I take your proposed solution to get it connected to the client http connection that posted the request and waiting on the same connection to the result?

Comment: @AvihooMamka Client sends a request, then `long_task` sends a message to RabbitMQ with an appropriate correlation id. Then `long_task` is locked until RabbitMQ responds. After that `long_task` responds to the client. This "`long_task` is locked" part is what the article I've linked is about. In other words you can wait **synchronously** for RabbitMQ to respond. It's a feature. :) See the code for `FibonacciRpcClient` and try it.

Comment: I got that part of using the RPC, but you said that there is a second approach with the raw TCP sockets, and this was bit unclear for me, but maybe the first RPC approach is easier to implement, Thanks.

Comment: @AvihooMamka Oh, right, sorry. So for the TCP solution your client have to open another TCP connection for notifications (or it can solely use TCP connections, but that would require total reimplementation of everything you have). Then you simply return from `long_task` with something like "I've received the request". And when the response (from RabbitMQ) reaches your backend, it searches for the appropriate TCP connection and pushes the data to the client. So the client doesn't receive the response through the initial request. It has to implement additional logic for handling notifications.

Comment: But yeah, don't go down that road. There are lots of subtle issues that are automatically solved over HTTP (or any stateless, one directional protocol). RPC should be fine in your case. Implement TCP/WS only when absolutely needed, i.e. when performance demands it.